# MUI Collapse animation / transition with margin in Material-UI

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I've been using [MUI-Collapse](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/collapse/) component to render out collapsible content in a list. I'd like my list to have vertical spacing between the Collapse components of the list, but I don't want the spacing to persist when the Collapse is collapsed, and I'm struggling to implement a nice solution.

[image]

The best I have so far, I've tried setting `margin-top` on the Collapse component only when the Collapse is in expanded state, and applying a transition to that property, but it still looks odd because that transition is delayed. Is there a way to get the spacing/margin to be included in the transition animation to make the animation smooth?

Here is a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-mclaren-csg2wg?file=/src/App.tsx

Would be great to hear any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more investigating, I discovered a solution - applying the `margin-top` to the actual inner wrapper item itself resolved the issue.

e.g.:

```
"& .MuiCollapse-wrapperInner": {
    marginTop: "20px"
  }
```

I guess that forces the collapsing component to ensure the transition is applied to the whole content, including the specified margins? This results in the nice, smooth animation.

[image]